Show that $ |\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})|=\mathfrak{c}$
Show that $ |\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})|=\mathfrak{c}$
Attempt:
In order to prove that  $\lvert\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\rvert=\mathfrak{c}=\lvert\mathbb{R}\rvert$, we know $\mathbb{R}\sim (0,1)\sim\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ and it is sufficient to show injective
$$f:(0,1)\to\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$$
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
\{m,n\} & \text{if } x\in\{\frac{m}{n}: \gcd(m,n)=1, m\in\mathbb{Z},n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\neq 0}\}\cap(0,1), \\
\{x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5x_6x_7x_8x_9\ldots\} & \text{if } 
 x=0.x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5x_6x_7x_8x_9\ldots \text{infinite but no repeating loop}
\end{cases}
$$
Every form of rational $\frac{m}{n}$ with $\gcd(m,n)=1$ is unique, then $f(x)=\{m,n\}$ must be injective. For $x$ be irrational number, every distinct irrational must differ in at least one digit, then so as $\{x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5x_6x_7x_8x_9\ldots\}$

We also need to demonstrate another way injective function, each $x\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ may written as $x=\{x_1<x_2<x_3,\dots\}$, and each $x_i\in\mathbb{N} $
\begin{align*}
g:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})&\to\mathbb{R}^{\infty} \\
x&\to(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)
\end{align*}
If $x$ is finite, fill the rest entries with $0$.   Each $x\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ must distinct either two ways, having at least one distinct ${x_1,x_2,x_3\ldots}$ or $x$ with different cardinality. Therefore, every distinct $x\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ with same cardinality must corresponds to distinct $(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)$ differ in at least one entries. Different cardinalty
$x$ must differ at $n$-th to fill with $0.$

I retrieve my tutorial question and remember the tutor said my first injection was wrong, I can't remember the reason exactly, somewhat "$x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5x_6x_7x_8x_9$" without ending is not a number. If this argument is valid, then how does one explicitly call a irrational number? e.g. $0.7856905132\ldots$ is this a valid number ?  I don't see why my first injection is not correct.
Is my second part of another way injection correct ?
Many Thanks

Better and easier approach : Every natural number can be or not be in some subset of $\mathbb N$. This can be converted into infinite binary strings. With Cantor you can then easily prove the uncountability.

@Peter Thank you for your reply. For your first sentence, I understand it as the $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ equinumerous to  ${\text{all indicator functions}:\mathbb{1}_A: \mathbb{N}\to{0,1} }$. However, for second and third sentence, I have no clear idea about what you said.

The $n$ th bit of the infinite binary string simply is $1$ if $n$ is in the powerset and $0$ , else.
